# Not finding import image file

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.9

I tried to import bulk image dataflow profile,

this is my export format:

[image]

this is my import format :

[image]

this is my excel format in which I export,

[image]

then I import the exported excel file and get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please use text instead of images so your question can be more easily searched for.

Comment: May be infographics more comfortable then text.

Comment: Stackoverflow prefers text over images. Please change your question to reflect that.

Comment: This seems to be about using Magento, not programming for it.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create import folder inside media folder

Step2: manage you csv file , Only add "/imagename.jpg" in your images
columns